# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am getting the following error; how to resolve this?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ScriptTimeout' and no extension method 'ScriptTimeout' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 120:                global::ASP.default_aspx.@__initialized = true;
Line 121:            }
Line 122:            this.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000000;
Line 123:        }
Line 124:        


Source File: c:\Users\jaison.p\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0741248\89bbda0d\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.qmt-gqly.0.cs    Line: 122


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Users\jaison.p\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0741248\89bbda0d\assembly\dl3\f4fc9365\e9cdf0a2_67c0ca01\BVParser.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /out:"C:\Users\jaison.p\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0741248\89bbda0d\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.qmt-gqly.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-  "C:\Users\jaison.p\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0741248\89bbda0d\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.qmt-gqly.0.cs" "C:\Users\jaison.p\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0741248\89bbda0d\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.qmt-gqly.1.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.4926
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\Users\jaison.p\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f0741248\89bbda0d\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.qmt-gqly.0.cs(122,25): error CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ScriptTimeout' and no extension method 'ScriptTimeout' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Show Complete Compilation Source:

Line 1:    #pragma checksum "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "46D3FBC1BF84CDBC9DAD256F03CF45DE"
Line 2:    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 3:    // <auto-generated>
Line 4:    //     This code was generated by a tool.
Line 5:    //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.4927
Line 6:    //
Line 7:    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
Line 8:    //     the code is regenerated.
Line 9:    // </auto-generated>
Line 10:   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 11:   
Line 12:   namespace ASP {
Line 13:       
Line 14:       #line 285 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 15:       using System.Web.Profile;
Line 16:       
Line 17:       #line default
Line 18:       #line hidden
Line 19:       
Line 20:       #line 280 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 21:       using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Line 22:       
Line 23:       #line default
Line 24:       #line hidden
Line 25:       
Line 26:       #line 282 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 27:       using System.Web.Caching;
Line 28:       
Line 29:       #line default
Line 30:       #line hidden
Line 31:       
Line 32:       #line 278 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 33:       using System.Configuration;
Line 34:       
Line 35:       #line default
Line 36:       #line hidden
Line 37:       
Line 38:       #line 277 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 39:       using System.Collections.Specialized;
Line 40:       
Line 41:       #line default
Line 42:       #line hidden
Line 43:       
Line 44:       #line 14 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 45:       using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
Line 46:       
Line 47:       #line default
Line 48:       #line hidden
Line 49:       
Line 50:       #line 289 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 51:       using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
Line 52:       
Line 53:       #line default
Line 54:       #line hidden
Line 55:       
Line 56:       #line 14 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 57:       using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 58:       
Line 59:       #line default
Line 60:       #line hidden
Line 61:       
Line 62:       #line 14 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 63:       using System.Web.UI;
Line 64:       
Line 65:       #line default
Line 66:       #line hidden
Line 67:       
Line 68:       #line 276 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 69:       using System.Collections;
Line 70:       
Line 71:       #line default
Line 72:       #line hidden
Line 73:       
Line 74:       #line 275 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 75:       using System;
Line 76:       
Line 77:       #line default
Line 78:       #line hidden
Line 79:       
Line 80:       #line 284 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 81:       using System.Web.Security;
Line 82:       
Line 83:       #line default
Line 84:       #line hidden
Line 85:       
Line 86:       #line 281 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 87:       using System.Web;
Line 88:       
Line 89:       #line default
Line 90:       #line hidden
Line 91:       
Line 92:       #line 283 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 93:       using System.Web.SessionState;
Line 94:       
Line 95:       #line default
Line 96:       #line hidden
Line 97:       
Line 98:       #line 279 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config"
Line 99:       using System.Text;
Line 100:      
Line 101:      #line default
Line 102:      #line hidden
Line 103:      
Line 104:      
Line 105:      [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 106:      public class default_aspx : global::BVParser._Default, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
Line 107:          
Line 108:          private static bool @__initialized;
Line 109:          
Line 110:          private static object @__fileDependencies;
Line 111:          
Line 112:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 113:          public default_aspx() {
Line 114:              string[] dependencies;
Line 115:              ((global::BVParser._Default)(this)).AppRelativeVirtualPath = "~/Default.aspx";
Line 116:              if ((global::ASP.default_aspx.@__initialized == false)) {
Line 117:                  dependencies = new string[1];
Line 118:                  dependencies[0] = "~/Default.aspx";
Line 119:                  global::ASP.default_aspx.@__fileDependencies = this.GetWrappedFileDependencies(dependencies);
Line 120:                  global::ASP.default_aspx.@__initialized = true;
Line 121:              }
Line 122:              this.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000000;
Line 123:          }
Line 124:          
Line 125:          protected System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile Profile {
Line 126:              get {
Line 127:                  return ((System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile)(this.Context.Profile));
Line 128:              }
Line 129:          }
Line 130:          
Line 131:          protected System.Web.HttpApplication ApplicationInstance {
Line 132:              get {
Line 133:                  return ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(this.Context.ApplicationInstance));
Line 134:              }
Line 135:          }
Line 136:          
Line 137:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 138:          private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle @__BuildControl__control3() {
Line 139:              global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle @__ctrl;
Line 140:              
Line 141:              #line 7 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 142:              @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle();
Line 143:              
Line 144:              #line default
Line 145:              #line hidden
Line 146:              return @__ctrl;
Line 147:          }
Line 148:          
Line 149:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 150:          private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead @__BuildControl__control2() {
Line 151:              global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead @__ctrl;
Line 152:              
Line 153:              #line 6 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 154:              @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead("head");
Line 155:              
Line 156:              #line default
Line 157:              #line hidden
Line 158:              global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle @__ctrl1;
Line 159:              
Line 160:              #line 6 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 161:              @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControl__control3();
Line 162:              
Line 163:              #line default
Line 164:              #line hidden
Line 165:              System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));
Line 166:              
Line 167:              #line 6 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 168:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);
Line 169:              
Line 170:              #line default
Line 171:              #line hidden
Line 172:              return @__ctrl;
Line 173:          }
Line 174:          
Line 175:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 176:          private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox @__BuildControlCluster() {
Line 177:              global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox @__ctrl;
Line 178:              
Line 179:              #line 14 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 180:              @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
Line 181:              
Line 182:              #line default
Line 183:              #line hidden
Line 184:              this.Cluster = @__ctrl;
Line 185:              @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
Line 186:              
Line 187:              #line 14 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 188:              @__ctrl.ID = "Cluster";
Line 189:              
Line 190:              #line default
Line 191:              #line hidden
Line 192:              return @__ctrl;
Line 193:          }
Line 194:          
Line 195:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 196:          private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox @__BuildControlServer() {
Line 197:              global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox @__ctrl;
Line 198:              
Line 199:              #line 15 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 200:              @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
Line 201:              
Line 202:              #line default
Line 203:              #line hidden
Line 204:              this.Server = @__ctrl;
Line 205:              @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
Line 206:              
Line 207:              #line 15 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 208:              @__ctrl.ID = "Server";
Line 209:              
Line 210:              #line default
Line 211:              #line hidden
Line 212:              return @__ctrl;
Line 213:          }
Line 214:          
Line 215:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 216:          private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm @__BuildControlform1() {
Line 217:              global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm @__ctrl;
Line 218:              
Line 219:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 220:              @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
Line 221:              
Line 222:              #line default
Line 223:              #line hidden
Line 224:              this.form1 = @__ctrl;
Line 225:              
Line 226:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 227:              @__ctrl.ID = "form1";
Line 228:              
Line 229:              #line default
Line 230:              #line hidden
Line 231:              System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));
Line 232:              
Line 233:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 234:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n    <div>\r\n    \r\n    </div>\r\n    "));
Line 235:              
Line 236:              #line default
Line 237:              #line hidden
Line 238:              global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox @__ctrl1;
Line 239:              
Line 240:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 241:              @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControlCluster();
Line 242:              
Line 243:              #line default
Line 244:              #line hidden
Line 245:              
Line 246:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 247:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);
Line 248:              
Line 249:              #line default
Line 250:              #line hidden
Line 251:              
Line 252:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 253:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n    "));
Line 254:              
Line 255:              #line default
Line 256:              #line hidden
Line 257:              global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox @__ctrl2;
Line 258:              
Line 259:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 260:              @__ctrl2 = this.@__BuildControlServer();
Line 261:              
Line 262:              #line default
Line 263:              #line hidden
Line 264:              
Line 265:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 266:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl2);
Line 267:              
Line 268:              #line default
Line 269:              #line hidden
Line 270:              
Line 271:              #line 10 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 272:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n    "));
Line 273:              
Line 274:              #line default
Line 275:              #line hidden
Line 276:              return @__ctrl;
Line 277:          }
Line 278:          
Line 279:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 280:          private void @__BuildControlTree(default_aspx @__ctrl) {
Line 281:              
Line 282:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 283:              this.InitializeCulture();
Line 284:              
Line 285:              #line default
Line 286:              #line hidden
Line 287:              System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));
Line 288:              
Line 289:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 290:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3" +
Line 291:                          ".org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\r\n\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1" +
Line 292:                          "999/xhtml\" >\r\n"));
Line 293:              
Line 294:              #line default
Line 295:              #line hidden
Line 296:              global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead @__ctrl1;
Line 297:              
Line 298:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 299:              @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControl__control2();
Line 300:              
Line 301:              #line default
Line 302:              #line hidden
Line 303:              
Line 304:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 305:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);
Line 306:              
Line 307:              #line default
Line 308:              #line hidden
Line 309:              
Line 310:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 311:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n<body>\r\n    "));
Line 312:              
Line 313:              #line default
Line 314:              #line hidden
Line 315:              global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm @__ctrl2;
Line 316:              
Line 317:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 318:              @__ctrl2 = this.@__BuildControlform1();
Line 319:              
Line 320:              #line default
Line 321:              #line hidden
Line 322:              
Line 323:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 324:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl2);
Line 325:              
Line 326:              #line default
Line 327:              #line hidden
Line 328:              
Line 329:              #line 1 "C:\Users\jaison.p\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BVParser\BVParser\Default.aspx"
Line 330:              @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"));
Line 331:              
Line 332:              #line default
Line 333:              #line hidden
Line 334:          }
Line 335:          
Line 336:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 337:          protected override void FrameworkInitialize() {
Line 338:              base.FrameworkInitialize();
Line 339:              this.@__BuildControlTree(this);
Line 340:              this.AddWrappedFileDependencies(global::ASP.default_aspx.@__fileDependencies);
Line 341:              this.Request.ValidateInput();
Line 342:          }
Line 343:          
Line 344:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 345:          public override int GetTypeHashCode() {
Line 346:              return 1715224027;
Line 347:          }
Line 348:          
Line 349:          [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 350:          public override void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) {
Line 351:              base.ProcessRequest(context);
Line 352:          }
Line 353:      }
Line 354:  }
Line 355:  



Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Comment: See my answer, would be surprised if it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this before where I created a variable in my page with the name "Server". It clashes with the "Server" generated here by the ASP.NET compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since no one is answering I'll give it a shot, though I don't know ASP.net at all, but the error seems pretty obvious.

It says this:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ScriptTimeout' and no extension method 'ScriptTimeout' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

looking at your code, you do this assignment:

```
@__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
```

then this:

```
this.Server = @__ctrl;
```

And somewhere else you attempt this:

```
this.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000000;
```

Which apparantly isn't possible for a TextBox.

I may be completely wrong though. Did you write (parts of) this code and do you understand it? As it says "This code was generated by a tool."

Comment: Good observation given no exp with asp.net

Answer (score 1):

There is no ScriptTimeout method in the TextBox class.

See: [TextBox Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_members.aspx)

Why (how?) are you setting `this.Server` to equal a textbox?

`this.Server` is presumably by default the [Page.Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.server.aspx) property, for which there is a [ScriptTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx) property.

You may have somehow confused the designer into letting you have a naming conflict between a page property ('Server') and a control (you've named a TextBox 'Server'). I have no idea how, but recommend changing the name of your control, possibly rebuilding your designer file, recompiling, and watching everything magically work again.

Answer (score 0):

Line 122:

this.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000000;

According to the exception, "this" is a TextBox.  If you remove "this" from line 122 the exception may go away.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Name of The TextBox.Don't use "Server"